# Form repeater with select option does not work with ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery.repeater

[image]

I am trying to build the form repeater where ID and Datapoint are select tag. When I select ID than Datapoint will be taken from AJAX response and appended to option. In the picture you can see when I call for select for the first time the datapoint (select tag) is showing the values but when trying to add another the datapoint there is no response.

```
<form method="post" class="repeater" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div data-repeater-list="samplernetwork">
    <div data-repeater-item="data-repeater-item" class="row">
      <div class="mb-3 col-lg-2">
        <label for="id">ID</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="id" id="id">
          <option></option>
          {% for id in id %}
            <option value="{{id.id}}">{{id.id}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3 col-lg-2">
        <label for="datapoint">Datapoint</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="datapoint" id="datapoint"></select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 align-self-center">
        <div class="d-grid">
          <input data-repeater-delete="data-repeater-delete" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <input data-repeater-create="data-repeater-create" type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-3 mt-lg-0" value="Add"/>

</form>

<script src="/libs/jquery.repeater/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pages/form-repeater.int.js"></script>

<script>
  $("#id").on('change', function (e) {
    var consti = $(this).val()
    console.log(consti)
    if (consti === "") {
      $('#datapoint').find('option').remove()
    } else if (consti != null) {
      var url = '{{path(' app_info ',{' id ':' ReplaceMeWithCorrectValue '})}}';
      url = url.replace("ReplaceMeWithCorrectValue", consti);
      var options = ""
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        success: function (response) {
          var information = JSON.parse(response)
          for (let item in information) {
            options += `<option value=${item}>${item}</option>`;
          }
          $("#datapoint").html(options);
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: You cannot use same *ID* for multiple elements .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the code

```
<form id="repeater-form">
  <div class="repeater">
    <div data-repeater-list="group-a">
      <div data-repeater-item>
        <select name="field-1" class="field-1">
          <option value="">Select an option</option>
          <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <select name="field-2" class="field-2" disabled>
          <option value="">Select an option</option>
        </select>
        <button data-repeater-delete type="button">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button data-repeater-create type="button">Add</button>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.repeater/1.2.1/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.repeater').repeater({
    initEmpty: false,
    show: function () {
      $(this).slideDown();
    },
    hide: function (deleteElement) {
      if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
        $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on('change', '.field-1', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var $field2 = $(this).closest('div[data-repeater-item]').find('.field-2');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'options.php',
      data: {'value': selectedValue},
      success: function (response) {
        var options = JSON.parse(response);
        var select = $field2;
        select.empty();
        select.append('<option value="">Select an option</option>');
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          select.append('<option value="' + options[i].value + '">' + options[i].text + '</option>');
        }
        select.prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });
  });

  $('#repeater-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'server-script.php',
      data: formData,
      success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```